# Showing a matrix is non-derogatory

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial, companion-matrices

Prove that the matrix

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 
       0      & 1 & \\
       \ddots &   & \ddots \\
              & \ddots & & \ddots \\
              &        & \ddots & & \ddots\\
              &        &        & 0 & & 1\\
       -a_{0} & -a_{1} & \dots  & \dots & \dots & -a_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}$$

is non-derogatory. I am not sure how would I do this. Non-derogatory matrix means that the minimal polynomial equals the characteristic polynomial but I am not sure how to this one.

Comment: See [Companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix).

Comment: Yes a companion matrix the charectertistic polynomial equals the minimal polynomial

Comment: So wait would would this be the transpose of the comparison matrix

Comment: My proof is the following the transpose of my matrix $A$ is $A^T$ and the tranpose of A is the companion matrix. And A is always similar to its tranpose. And if two matrices are similar their characteristic polynomial and the minimum polynomial so then let P be the charecteristic polynomial and Q be the mimum polynomial so $P_{A}(t)=P_{A^T}(T)=Q_{A^T}(t)=Q_{A^T}(t)$ thus a is non derogatory

Comment: @FernandoMartinez: While all that is true, it uses the somewhat non-obvious (an unnatural) fact that a matrix is always similar to its transpose. It is easier to see that minimal and characteristic polynomials of $A^T$ are always the same as the respective ones for $A$, which suffices here to deduce the result from the one for companion matrices.